# Can we have value inside properties file as an array of values?

Tags: java, android

I have a properties file.
I know that its possible to give

```
key = value1, value2,value3
```

inside properties file.

My requirement is like:

```
key = value1[1, 2], value2[3,4]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can but after that you should write parser that split with "[ ]"and ","

value is just a string like that :

```
String value = p.getProperty(key)
```

and here your value is `value = "value1[1, 2], value2[3,4]"`

but don't do this think a smarter way

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to change the property file stucture to have something like this:

```
key.array0 = 1,2
key.array1 = 3,4
```

Now filter on fragment `"key.array*"`, create arrays from all values and add the list of arrays to your map.